# Fastest way to add noise to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-random

I have a numpy.ndarray that represents an image and I would like to add random noise to it. I've done some tests and so far the fastest solution I have is to do:

```
def RandomNoise(x):
    x += np.random.random(x.shape)
```

But when I have big images/arrays, this solution is still really too slow. What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: If `x` is an image then I assume it's all integers (like RGB output)?  `np.random.random` returns a float, so your overhead may be time spent converting everything to floats.

Comment: It won't get faster than this. You need `prod(x.shape)` many random numbers, and `np.random.rand` is the fastest here. For adding one array to another, there's nothing better than `+` either. Let me add that I'd be surprised if this is the choking point of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but in my case I have to work with float :-(

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to make this faster is to avoid allocating the random array which you don't actually need.  To avoid that, use Numba:

```
import numba
import random

@numba.njit
def RandomNoise2(x):
    x = x.reshape(-1) # flat view
    for ii in range(len(x)):
        x[ii] += random.random()
```

For moderate-size arrays like 4 million elements, this is slightly faster after the first run when it JIT-compiles the code.  For larger arrays like 20 million values it is twice as fast, or more.  If you're low on memory it will be massively faster, because it will avoid swapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I am not expert with python, so I am surprised by this line `x = x.ravel()`.  Don't you modify the shape of x?

Comment: I guess that because my array has 3 dimensions (a stack of images), I can probably speed up the process using multi-threading.

Comment: I've done the test for an array [27, 1600, 1600], so approximately 69 millions floats, and the processing time goes down from 2.7s to 1.5s, so almost twice faster.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: When testing, make sure you run the function several times.  The first run will be slower due to JIT compilation.  Regarding ravel(), I realized a better and clearer way is `reshape(-1)` so I will update the answer to use that.  It generally won't copy the input.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: Anyway it doesn't "modify x" - notice that I reassign the variable x to the result of ravel/reshape.  If you prefer to be more clear you can use a different variable name like y inside the function everywhere except `x.reshape(-1)`.